# nginx gzip compression doesn't seem to work

Tags: nginx, gzip

I'm trying to figure out why my custom CDN on nginx, doesn't appear to be working. Here is what I have in my site configuration:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name cdn.site.co.uk;

    root /srv/www/site.co.uk/bob_user;

    if ($uri !~ "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://site.co.uk/ permanent;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

}
```

The file itself works - but using this tool, it tells me that it does:

https://varvy.com/tools/gzip/

[image]

This is the URL I tested:

http://cdn.businessofbrands.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js

I'm a bit confused as to why this is. Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: I believe this may be because you're missing `application/javascript` from `gzip_types` (which is the content-type used for `jquery.js`)

Comment: @Sean3z - ah man, not sure how I missed that! Works like a charm now :) Please add that as an answer, and I'll accept as soon as it lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `application/javascript` is missing from `gzip_types`.

You'll want to add it to the following line:

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
```

Actually, `text/javascript` is [obsolete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) so you could just replace it :)